# How to output only the latest screen with php exec?

Tags: php, bash, exec

My problem is:

I have large output files generated with the exec command. I have about 800-1500 MB of text output, because it's appended to my text file every second. How could I only write the last piece of data to my text file?

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
$cmd = 'btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/'.$kovNev.'/ '.$_REQUEST["torrent"];
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

I would like to see this in my output file:

```
saving:         Test torrent (1115.9 MB)
percent done:   19.8
time left:      22 min 04 sec
download to:    /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370552248/
download rate:  1344.1 kB/s
upload rate:    115.7 kB/s
share rating:   0.121  (26.8 MB up / 221.3 MB down)
seed status:    81 seen now, plus 3.994 distributed copies
peer status:    18 seen now, 45.3% done at 2175.4 kB/s
```

And not this:

```
saving:         Test torrent (1115.9 MB)
percent done:   19.8
time left:      22 min 04 sec
download to:    /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370552248/
download rate:  1344.1 kB/s
upload rate:    115.7 kB/s
share rating:   0.121  (26.8 MB up / 221.3 MB down)
seed status:    81 seen now, plus 3.994 distributed copies
peer status:    18 seen now, 45.3% done at 2175.4 kB/s
saving:         Test torrent (1115.9 MB)
percent done:   19.8
time left:      22 min 04 sec
download to:    /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370552248/
download rate:  1344.1 kB/s
upload rate:    115.7 kB/s
share rating:   0.121  (26.8 MB up / 221.3 MB down)
seed status:    81 seen now, plus 3.994 distributed copies
peer status:    18 seen now, 45.3% done at 2175.4 kB/s
saving:         Test torrent (1115.9 MB)
percent done:   19.8
time left:      22 min 04 sec
download to:    /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370552248/
download rate:  1344.1 kB/s
upload rate:    115.7 kB/s
share rating:   0.121  (26.8 MB up / 221.3 MB down)
seed status:    81 seen now, plus 3.994 distributed copies
peer status:    18 seen now, 45.3% done at 2175.4 kB/s ...etc...
```

So I would like to see only the latest screen. My bash command append the output txt an not rewriting it. I want to rewrite it.

Comment: I have found this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html It's writting about this bash thing, but I don't understood why my bash script append that txt and not only delete it and create new..

Comment: What command is in `$cmd` and what do you mean by `last piece of data` : Last line of output of `$cmd`, last character of output of `$cmd` or `$!`?

Comment: `$cmd = 'btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/'.$kovNev.'/   '.$_REQUEST["torrent"];` ... This is my cmd $_REQUEST["torrent"] is an url of a torrent file.

Comment: Add this to the question. Also add in the question what you want out of the output of this command. That is last line, last character, last page or command status?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very simple. Download programs usually give a status bar on screen. How that status bar is drawn is that the screen is cleaned of the old status bar and the new one is displayed on top of it. However, if the output is redirected to a file, screen blanking and new output keeps on getting written to the output file, making it's size really really large.

With that in mind, you're left with 2 options:

- Use `tail` to limit the output to 9 lines before sending the output to the file. Your error output will be need to be redirected to a separate file and read back as required. However, the pid is lost as `$!` is the pid of `less` .

  ```
  exec(sprintf("%s 2>error_file | tail -n 9 > %s & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
  ```
- use mkfifo to create pipes, write output to pipe and use tail on the other end of the pipe to write to output file. This complicates the command into a full scriptlet

  ```
  exec(sprintf("tdir=`mktemp -d`; mkfifo $tdir/fifo; %s >$tdir/fifo 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s & tail -n 9 $tdir/fifo > %s &", $cmd, $pidfile, $outputfile));
  ```

To explain it, `mktemp -d` creates a temp dir and returns it's name(stored in `tdir`). `$tdir/fifo` is the name chosen for the fifo and is guaranteed to be unique given the properties of `mktemp`. The command output is sent to the fifo, and pid is stored in the `pidfile`. However, to write to the `outputfile`, we use `tail -n 9 $tdir/fifo` to read from the `$tdir/fifo` and keep reading the last 9 lines in the `$tdir/fifo` up until the process writing to the fifo finishes, and then write them to the standard output which is redirect to `$outputfile`. Now as `$tdir/fifo` is a fifo, no disk space is used.

Comment: You descripted it a lot. Your second example dont work on my server, but first example almost works. It creates the pidfile and it creates the output file, but my output file is empty.

Comment: @tigyijanos I worked on the assumption that you're working on a system which has `mktemp`, and `mkfifo` available and uses `/` as a path separator. Please let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: How can I check my system for mktemp and mkfifo? .. I use linux, debian.

Comment: You should have them if it's debian. These are core system utilities. execute `which mkfifo` and `which mktemp` and use the full paths instead of just the command names. That might solve the problem.

Comment: If you means this: **exec("`tdir=`/bin/mktemp -d`; /usr/bin/mkfifo /fifo; btdownloadheadless --saveas /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/uid1_fil_1370612064/ http://ca.isohunt.com/download/459773481/free.torrent >/fifo 2>&1 & echo $! >> /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/folyamatok/uid1_fil_1370612064_id.txt & tail -n 9 /fifo > /var/www/virtual/tigyisolutions.hu/boxy/htdocs/downloaded_torrent/folyamatok/uid1_fil_1370612064.txt`");** ... It dont work. It gives me empty output file.

Comment: can you try `exec("tdir=\`/bin/mktemp -d\`; echo $tdir; ls -ld $tdir")`. This should give you some output like `/tmp/garbled_name`.